# Why doesn't my UIView update and show intermediate results?

Tags: performance, uiimage, dispatch-async

In my app I want to stack a large number of (identical PNG) files on top of each other and show the user the image-result as well as the progress-bar. In order to improve performance I came up with the following code, but only when the for-loop finishes I'll see the end-result.
For large sets of images this is not what I want, and I really want to see intermediate results. The following code probably contains errors, which I can't find yet:

```
- (IBAction)doDrawLayers:(NSArray *)drawImages
{
    // Use dispath-queues for drawing intermediate result and progress. 
    _startDrawing = [NSDate date];
    dispatch_queue_t calcImage = dispatch_queue_create("calcImage", NULL);
    dispatch_async(calcImage, ^{
        _sldProgress.maximumValue = drawImages.count;
        _sldProgress.minimumValue = 0;
        _imageNr = 0;
        [_sldProgress setMaximumValue:drawImages.count];
        for (NSString *imageFile in drawImages) {
            @autoreleasepool {
                // Update in main queue.
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(_imageSize);
                    // Show progress update.
                    _lblProgress.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %.2f sec", ++_imageNr, -[_startDrawing timeIntervalSinceNow]];
                    _sldProgress.value = _imageNr;
                    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imageFile ofType:nil];
                    [[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath] drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0., 0.)];
                    // Get CGImage from the offscreen image context.
                    _imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
                    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
                });
            }
        }
    });
    // Finished calculating image, release dispatch.
    dispatch_release(calcImage);
}
```

I'm also struggling with the question of whats the best place to put the UIGraphicsBeginImageContext/UIGraphicsEndImageContext-pair, since I want to minimize the amount of memory being used and maximize the overall performance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution by merging code from Apple's PhotoScroller (mainly based on CATiledLayer) and LargeImageDownsizing example code.